# BULK INSERT 0 Rows affected

Tags: sql, t-sql, csv, import

I have been at this problem all morning and can't seem to figure it out. I have a simple txt file with the following entries:

1,van Rhijn

2,van Dam

3,van Rhijn van Dam

I am trying to import these fields using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

BULK INSERT #test
FROM 'C:\test.txt'
WITH
(
    MAXERRORS = 0,
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)

SELECT *
FROM #test
```

I have tried everything I found on the web. Changing delimitor, row terminator, encoding, extension. I keep getting the message "0 row(s) affected" and the last select obviously returns no rows.

EDIT: I use Microsoft SQL Server.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Sybase? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag because the syntax isnt MySQL syntax

Comment: I use MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a silly question, but are you actually using the syntax 'test.txt' or are you using a fully qualified or at least a full path like 'c:\test.txt'? Because I am pretty sure you need to use the full path here.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

BULK INSERT #test
FROM 'C:\test.txt'
WITH
(
    MAXERRORS = 0,
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

SELECT *
FROM #test
```

Or wherever your file resides on the network (note if your SQL server is on a different machine you will probably need to use a network path and/or shared folder combination).

edit: Try updating your ROWTERMINATOR to \n only

Comment: YesI am using a full path. Just simplified the path for this question. Updated question for clarification.

Comment: Try changing the row terminator. If you have a text editor like Notepad++ you can turn on the invisible characters and see if you actually have NewLine or Return characters or both. I have updated my answer with the full code. I tested this on my machine and it worked with only \n instead of both \r\n.

Comment: As stated I tried this (problably did something else wrong) but somehow when I tried it after you answer it worked! Thanks.